# How do I create some variable type alias in Java

Tags: java, types, hashmap, alias

let say I have this code

```
Map<String, String> list = new HashMap<String, String>();
list.put("number1", "one");
list.put("number2", "two");
```

how can I make some "alias" the type

```
Map<String, String>
```

to something that easier to be rewritten like

```
// may be something like this
theNewType = HashMap<String, String>;

theNewType list = new theNewType();
list.put("number1", "one");
list.put("number2", "two");
```

basically my question is, how to create "alias" to some "type", so i can make it easier to write and easier when need to change the whole program code.

Thanks, and sorry if this is silly question. I'm kinda new in Java.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

There are no aliases in Java. You can extend the `HashMap` class with your class like this:

```
public class TheNewType extends HashMap<String, String> {
    // default constructor
    public TheNewType() {
        super();
    }
    // you need to implement the other constructors if you need
}
```

But keep in mind that this will be a class it won't be the same as you type `HashMap<String, String>`

Comment: @Lee - KARASZI István's caveat about types is important - see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02216/index.html

Comment: There is an alternative trick/hack you can do with generics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604390/how-do-i-create-some-variable-type-alias-in-java/27536347#27536347

Comment: But because this is a specialization of a more general type, you can't use `TheNewType` in place of `HashMap<String, String>` as much as you can't use the latter where a `Map<String, String>` is returned.

Comment: archive of link posted by @McDowell https://web.archive.org/web/20170206190605/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02216/index.html

Answer (score 18):

There is no `typedef` equivalent in Java, and there is no common idiom for aliasing types. I suppose you could do something like

```
class StringMap extends HashMap<String, String> {}
```

but this is not common and would not be obvious to a program maintainer.

Comment: Bear in mind that you should implement the missing details of the Serializable interface for your subclass, should you do this. Else, you may encounter curiosities if you ever run into a situation where you need to (de)serialize your object.

Answer (score 12):

Although Java doesn't support this, you can use a generics trick to simulate it.

```
class Test<I extends Integer> {
    <L extends Long> void x(I i, L l) {
        System.out.println(
            i.intValue() + ", " + 
            l.longValue()
        );
    }
}
```

Source: http://blog.jooq.org/2014/11/03/10-things-you-didnt-know-about-java/

Comment: IMO this is the same idea as in the other answers, in that you use the concept of derivation to get a new type name. Here it is `I` from `Integer` and `L` from `Long` by constraining type variables, where the other answers propose `NewType` from `HashMap<String,String>` by constructing a new class. The drawback of the type variable approach is that you can only use it within the scope of the type variables, e.g. the `Test` class or the `x` method.

Answer (score 4):

The closest one could think of is to make a wrapper class like so

```
class NewType extends HashMap<String, String> {
     public NewType() { }
}
```

I really wish Java had a sound type aliasing feature.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like that exists in Java. You might be able to do something with IDE templates or autocompletion, and look forward to (limited) [generics type inference](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20is%20the%20diamond%20operator?) in Java 7.