# Replacing Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> with Short type

Tags: java

I have some Map 0f Map 0f List

I created such interface for shorthand it

```
public interface ShortName extends Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>
```

But when I try to instantiate real object it give me `ClassCastExcpetion`

```
ShortName testObj = (ShortName) new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<String>>>();
```

Is there any way to make short type for Map

Comment: No. No type aliases in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have a concept of type aliasing (see [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604390/how-do-i-create-some-variable-type-alias-in-java)), however you can make a new class, of a different type, which extends your `Map`;

```
class NewType extends HashMap<String, Map<String, List<String>>>
```

But this isn't a "shorthand" for that type, it's a new type altogether - so casting won't work etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to get a shorthand to work partly. You need to implement ShortName to make ShortName cast work.

You can do `public static class NewType extends HashMap<String, Map<String, List<String>>> implements ShortName {}`. And then you can use the cast to ShortName as in `ShortName testObj = (ShortName) new NewType();`

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ShortName testObj = (ShortName) new NewType();
        System.out.println("ok");
    }

    public interface ShortName extends Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> {

    }

    public static class NewType extends HashMap<String, Map<String, List<String>>> implements ShortName {}
}
```