# Fix left side in Either of Java Vavr

Tags: java, functional-programming, vavr

I want to avoid:

```
Either<Error, Employee> processEmployee(Employee e)
```

and use:

```
Result<Employee> processEmployee(Employee e)
```

where left is fixed:

```
Result<T> extends Either<Error, T>
```

Is there an example of this?

When I try this nothing compiles for me and I'm forced to implement a concrete class of `Result<T>` which I want to avoid.

The reason I want to do this is to simplify the method signatures and the stream code that uses these methods.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [type aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604390/how-do-i-create-some-variable-type-alias-in-java), a feature which Java regrettably does not support.

Comment: It might work if you override all the methods that return `Either` and create some static method where you can provide an `Either` and return a `Result`. I ran into the same thing with Validation, but I'm a bit reluctant to override everything, it doesn't feel right on how we use vavr currently.

Comment: If your always going to use Either with your Error type maybe you could use Try instead and extend your type Error from Exception

Answer (score 0):

What about using `toTry` method from `Value` interface? Your code could look like:

```java
public Try<Employee> processEmployee(Employee e){
  //… blebleble

  var someEither<Error, Employee> = eitherResult();

  return someEither.toTry();
}
```

You have „simplified” type that contains everything that you need and contains `toEither()` method (if you need that).